Segmentation Fault in x86 Assembly
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int Min(int A, int B) {
    return A < B ? A : B;
}

int solution(string s) {
    int answer = s.length();
    for (int Len = 1; Len <= s.length() / 2; Len++) {
        string Result = "";
        string Temp = s.substr(0, Len);
        int Cnt = 1;
        int i;
        for (i = Len; i <= s.length(); i = i + Len) {
            if (Temp == s.substr(i, Len)) 
                Cnt++;
            else {
                if (Cnt == 1) 
                    Result += Temp;
                else {
                    Result += to_string(Cnt);
                    Result += Temp;
                }
                Temp = s.substr(i, Len);
                Cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        if (i > s.length()) {
            if (Cnt == 1) 
                Result += Temp;
            else {
                Result += to_string(Cnt);
                Result += Temp;
            }
        }
        answer = Min(answer, Result.length());
    }
    return answer;
}

I'm working on writing the x86 version of the above code, which includes a loop for comparing and compressing two strings. However, my code is causing a segmentation fault, and I suspect that the following loop is causing the issue. This is my x86 code.
compress:
    mov rcx, len 
    cmp rcx, 1
    je len1
    shr rcx, 1 ; Repeat for half the length of the string, rcx = len/2
    mov rbx, 1 ; rbx = i, compression unit for the string
    mov rdx, len ; rdx stores the length of the array
    
compress_loop:
    cmp rbx,rcx ; If i > len/2, exit loop
    jg done
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx

    lea rsi, [array]
    lea rdi, [temp]
    lea r8, [result]

    call substr ; Copy i elements of array to temp
    xor r10, r10
    inc r10 ; count = 1

    mov r11, rbx ; r11 = j
    call compare

    push rsi
    call find_len
    pop rsi

    push rax
    call clean
    pop rax
    
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    inc rbx ; i++
    cmp rdx, rax ; Compare rax with the length of the array
    ja find_answer ; Store the smaller value in rdx
    jmp compress_loop
    
compare:
    cmp r11, rdx ; If j > len, exit loop
    jg compare_done
    
    mov r12, rsi
    add r12, r11 ; r12 = array[j]
    mov r13, rdi ; r13 = temp

    jmp compare_loop1

compare_loop1:
    mov al, byte[r13]
    mov bl, byte[r12]
    cmp al, 0 ; Until temp is finished, if al = bl, count + 1
    je count_plus
    cmp al, bl
    je compare_loop2
    jmp new
    
compare_loop2:
    inc r13
    inc r12
    jmp compare_loop1

compare_done : 
    ret
    
count_plus:
    inc r10 ; count + 1
    add r11, rbx ; j = j + i
    jmp compare
    
new :
    cmp r10, 1
    je copy_count1
    jmp copy_string

copy_count1:
    ; If count = 1, store temp in result, and store a new string in temp
    push rcx 
    push rsi ; array
    push rdi ; temp

    mov rsi, rdi
    mov rdi, r8
    mov rcx, rbx 
    rep movsb ; Store temp in result

    pop rdi ; rdi = temp
    call clean_temp ; Initialize temp to 0

    pop rsi
    add rsi, r11 ; rsi = array[j]
    rep movsb ; Store a new string in temp
    
    pop rcx
    sub rdi, rbx ; rdi = temp[0]
    lea rsi, [array] ; rsi = array[0]
    mov r10, 1 ; count = 1
    add r11, rbx ; j = j + i 

    jmp compare

copy_string : 
    ; If count != 1, store temp + count in result
    push rcx
    push rsi
    push rdi
    push rax
    
    mov rsi, rdi
    mov rdi, r8
    mov rcx, rbx
    rep movsb ; Store temp in result

    mov rax, r10
    call copy_count ; Add count to result
    
    pop rax
    pop rdi
    call clean_temp

    pop rsi
    add rsi, r11 ; rsi = array[j]
    rep movsb ; Store a new string in temp

    pop rcx
    sub rdi, rbx ; rdi = temp[0]
    lea rsi, [array] ; rsi = array[0]
    mov r10, 1 ; count = 1
    add r11, rbx ; j = j + i 

    jmp compare

I'm not sure how to debug this code. Help me find where the problem is.

This is not a [mcve]. Code is missing. Also your functions are using nonstandard calling conventions (or none at all) so it's hard to figure out what's wrong. For example, substr seems to be missing the length argument. Additionally it may destroy rsi that you later need. Anyway, as a first step, load the program into your debugger and see where it crashes.

In addition to using a debugger to see a stack trace at the exact point of fault, including its line number, you might get some insight by compiling the C++ with -S -O3.

You also don't seem to be respecting call preserved registers. Which ones those are depends on your OS, which you have not specified.
